# Laravel - whereDoesntHave in nested relations

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm running:

```
$products->whereDoesntHave('user.trainer');
```

The query that laravel makes is:

```
select *
from `products`
where not exists (
    select * from `users` where `products`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` and
    exists (
        select * from `trainers` where `users`.`id` = `trainers`.`user_id`
    )
)
```

While I want is:

```
select *
from `products`
where exists (  /* <---- */
    select * from `users` where `products`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` and
    not exists ( /* <---- */
        select * from `trainers` where `users`.`id` = `trainers`.`user_id`
    )
)
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain `whereHas()` with `doesntHave()` to retrieve the products where there is a users-relation that doesn't have a trainer.

```php
$products->whereHas('user', function($query) {
    return $query->doesntHave('trainer');
});
```